# NDB - Most Efficient Way to Delete a List of Keys

Tags: python-2.7, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

I believe I need to use `ndb.delete_multi` but I am confused as to how to make it work for a specific set of keys and whether it is the most efficient way to go.  Using Python 2.7 with Google App Engine.

First, I am collecting the keys that I want to delete.  I don't want to delete everything, only those entries that are 1 hour or more old.  Toward that end I first collect the list of keys that meet this criteria.

```
cs = ChannelStore()
delMsgKeys = []
for x in cs.allMessages():
   current = datetime.datetime.now()
   recordTime = x.channelMessageCreated
   timeDiffSecs = (current - recordTime).total_seconds()
   timeDiff = (timeDiffSecs/60)/60
   if timeDiff >=1:
      delMsgKeys.append(x.key.id())
ndb.delete_multi(?????)
```

The definition for cs.allMessages():

```
def allMessages(self):
        return ChannelStore.query().fetch()
```

First, is this overall the most efficient approach?  Second, how do I use the list of keys I created with the `ndb.delete_multi` statement?

---Update----

The issue with the ndb.delete_multi has to do with the keys I was passing it.  In the code I posted above the keys should have been stored as follows:

```
delMsgKeys.append(x.key)
```

With the above ndb.delete_multi works.

Answer (score 6):

Per the [NDB documentation](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/entities), you can just pass in a list of keys to `ndb.delete_multi`, so based on your code, this should work:

```
ndb.delete_multi(delMsgKeys)
```

I'm not sure what the limit is for the number of keys that you can pass in a single `ndb.delete_multi()` call, though.

For this query:

```
ChannelStore.query().fetch()
```

You can add an entity property to store a timestamp when you create/update the entity by adding `auto_now = True` ([more documentation here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/properties#Date_and_Time)). Then with the `timestamp` property you can query for something like this:

```
sixty_mins_ago = datetime.datetime.now()- datetime.timedelta(minutes = 60)
qry = ChannelStore.query()
list_of_keys = qry.filter(ChannelStore.timestamp < sixty_mins_ago).fetch(keys_only = True)
```

Since you don't need the entities, a `keys_only` fetch will be cheaper. Of course this code is assuming your `ChannelStore` model has a `timestamp` property, so your model will have to be something like this:

```
class ChannelStore(ndb.model):
    #other properties go here
    timestamp = ndb.DateTimeProperty(auto_now = True)
```

Putting it all together, something like this could work for the code block you have above:

```
from models import ChannelStore
from google.appengine.ext import ndb
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
# other imports

def delete_old_entities():
    sixty_mins_ago = datetime.now() - timedelta(minutes = 60)
    qry = ChannelStore.query()
    qry = qry.filter(ChannelStore.timestamp < sixty_mins_ago)
    list_of_keys = qry.fetch(keys_only = True)
    ndb.delete_multi(list_of_keys)
```

In case you have to delete a lot of keys and are running into some kind of API limit with the `ndb.delete_multi` call, you can change the `delete_old_entities()` method to the following:

```
def delete_old_entities():
    sixty_mins_ago = datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(minutes = 60)
    qry = ChannelStore.query()
    qry = qry.filter(ChannelStore.timestamp < sixty_mins_ago)
    list_of_keys = qry.fetch(keys_only = True)

    while list_of_keys:
        # delete 100 at a time
        ndb.delete_multi(list_of_keys[:100])
        list_of_keys = list_of_keys[100:]
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.  Before I get into the time portion I want to comment on the ndb.delete_multi.  I did go through their docs and like you I felt all I had to do was pass the keys.  However, it gives an error. Essentially the error boils down this line: "AttributeError: 'long' object has no attribute 'delete_async'"

Comment: I figured out part of the issue with the delete_multi.  I needed to pass it just "key" and not "key_id".  I will post an update above.

Comment: I do store a datetimeproperty.  I do see what you are suggesting with the code but I am not sure it saves anything.  I am still doing a query and then coming back with ndb.delete_multi.  Do you see an efficiency gain with the code you have posted over mine?

Comment: The biggest thing that I think will make things more efficient (cheaper, really) is that you're fetching the entire entity in your code, whereas a `keys_only` fetch would be cheaper. You don't need the entire entity just to delete it, but you will be billed for all of those datastore reads, whereas a `keys_only` query is [free](https://developers.google.com/appengine/pricing?csw=1#cost_resource). Also your code fetches *every* entity and you filter manually later, whereas I think it'd be faster to just fetch entities with a specific filter at the beginning.

Comment: To add, you could time the step of whether or not to filter before or after and see the difference -- my guess is it won't be significant. In any case, you should do a keys_only query to save money. Try appstats to see any differences, in particular with RPC calls, which are normally the rate limiting step in an app engine app.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I would imagine the query behind the keys only fetch is not free?  In other words is keys only free even if you use filters?  I understood fetches by key were free (DB Small Operation) but I didn't realize that query terms were also permitted free of charge (within a keys only return).  If that is the case I certainly understand where you are going here.